# Change "revert chunk" title string in codemirror merge view

Tags: javascript, merge, codemirror

I am trying to change the "revert chunk" string title of codemirror merge view. 
Can anyone tell me if this is doable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
_startPushToTooltip: function() {
    this._nPushToTooltipHandler = setInterval(function() {
        $(".CodeMirror-merge-copybuttons-left > .CodeMirror-merge-copy").prop("title", "push_to_right");
        $(".CodeMirror-merge-copybuttons-right > .CodeMirror-merge-copy").prop("title", "push_to_left");
    }, 500);
},

_stopPushToTooltipHandler: function() {
    clearInterval(this._nPushToTooltipHandler); 
},
```